# Expressão Regular que corresponda apenas números de 1 dígito, e nada mais

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma variável que pode armazenar diversos valores (palavras, letras, números, etc), dependendo de uma inserção em um campo tipo 'input'. Gostaria de fazer uma busca que relacione apenas números de 1 dígito (/\b\d{1}\b/), e qualquer outra informação presente no campo desse "false" como resultado. Ex:

```
var test = "1";
console.log(test.match(/\b\d{1}\b/)); // corresponde e portanto é 'true'
var test = "sp 1 inf"; // mesmo assim corresponde com "test.match(/\b\d{1}\b/)"
```

O que eu quero é uma modificação em "test.match(/\b\d{1}\b/)" que dá "false" como resultado no segundo caso (var test = "1 info"), portando, não correspondendo. Desde já, agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Em outras palavras, você quer que a regex case somente se a string inteira case, e não parte dela, é isso?

Comment: A propósito, para casar um único dígito você não precisa de `\d{1}`, só `\d` já basta...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando se utiliza `match`, procura-se na string algum trecho (substring) que corresponda à expressão regular usada, seja ele onde estiver. Como sua string **contém** um único dígito isolado, ele encontra esse dígito e retorna verdadeiro.

Se você quer que a expressão case a string **inteira**, não somente parte dela, use `^` no início para casar o "início da string" e `$` no final para casar o "fim da string":

```
^\b\d{1}\b$
```

Exemplo (também substituindo `\d{1}` por `\d`, pois isso é suficiente para casar um único caractere):

```js
var test = "1";
log(test.match(/\b\d\b/)); // corresponde e portanto é 'true'
log(test.match(/^\b\d\b$/)); // corresponde e portanto é 'true'

var test = "sp 1 inf";
log(test.match(/\b\d\b/)); // corresponde e portanto é 'true'
log(test.match(/^\b\d\b$/)); // não corresponde e portanto é 'false'


function log(x) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += "<p>" + x + "</p>";
}
```

Comment: Me disseram que *para casar um único dígito você não precisa de `\d{1}`, só `\d` já basta...*

Comment: @bfavaretto Hahaha ok, é que eu sempre prefiro mexer o mínimo possível no código do AP para responder a pergunta. *Confounding*, sabe... :P

Comment: Achei ótima sua solução. // test.match(/^\b\d\b$/) // Já tinha tentado antes e não havia funcionado. Agora há pouco descobri o porque. Em alguns casos haverá um espaço (\b) antes e talvez depois do número. A única dúvida que me resta é como como incluir essa possibilidade na solução proposta. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @eden `\b` não é um espaço, mas [a fronteira entre duas "palavras"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Espaços em branco em geral (incluindo tabulações) podem ser casados usando `\s`, e é claro, `\ ` (não tenho certeza se precisa escapar ou não, mas não atrapalha...) para pegar só o espaço comum. Portanto, para detectar zero ou um espaço antes e depois do número você pode usar `^\ ?\b\d\b\ ?$`

Comment: @mgibsonbr, Ontem mesmo descobri que para incluir possíveis espaços, deveria mantê-los fora da fronteira entre palavras (\b). No meu último comentário, confundi o \s com o \b, desculpe! Minha solução foi quase igual a sua ^\s*\b\d\b\s*$/, apenas não há limites p/ o nº de espaços, e funcionou perfeitamente bem em todos os testes que realizei. Bem, minhas dúvidas terminam aqui, agradeço muito sua prontidão e disposição de ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Se criares um grupo de captura para um número com `(\d)` e deres a flag *global* `g` para apanhar todos os casos vais ter uma array con a *length* correspondente ao numero de dígitos presentes na *string* (ou `null` se não houver numeros na string).

Assim se o que pretendes é saber se há um e só um numero podes verificar se essa array que o match retorna tem somente um elemento, `array.length == 1`.

```
function testa(str) {
    var match = str.match(/(\d)/g);
    return !!match && match.length == 1;
}

var a = "1"; 
var b = "sp 1 inf";
var c = "sp 1 inf 5";
var d = "sp inf";

console.log(testa(a)); // true
console.log(testa(b)); // true
console.log(testa(c)); // false (length é 2)
console.log(testa(d)); // false (match é null)
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lj27tzne/